# Disable automatic boxes in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Example with automatic boxes]

In VS Code 1.47.3 on Ubuntu, working in Python. If I put my cursor on some keyword, function name, object name, etc., all instances are automatically highlighted with a box that clutters up the code.  See attached pix where the cursor is on rand in the "z" line, but boxes pop up everywhere. Anyone know how to shut it off?

Happens in other languages too, so a VS Code setting somewhere...

Comment: It is the way the Theme colors matching words, try a different theme to see if it still is a box. You can customize that theme handling of matching words.

Comment: Or maybe the search box (either current editor or global search) is open with the term `rand`